# Update one column in a trigger after updating only particular column in the same table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, updates

I have the following table with this structure:

```SQL
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks]
(
    [TasksID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CommitteeID] [int] NULL,
    [TransactionDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [inspectionStatus] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Latitude] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Longitude] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [acceptanceState] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [comments] [nvarchar](350) NULL,
    [ScheduledDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
)
```

What I want exactly is to create a trigger that update `[TransactionDateTime]` with the current datetime, only if the column `[acceptanceState]` is updated.

I have created the following trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TransactionDateUpdate]
ON [dbo].[Tasks]
AFTER UPDATE  
AS BEGIN
   UPDATE dbo.Tasks
   SET TransactionDateTime = GETDATE()
   FROM INSERTED i
   WHERE i.TasksID = Tasks.TasksID 
END
```

The problem with this trigger, that it updates the column `[TransactionDateTime]` but if I made change on any of the column in the table, and what I want is to update `[TransactionDateTime]` only if the column `[acceptanceState]` is changed/updated. Can I find any help? How to add the condition of updating `[TransactionDateTime]` only if `[acceptanceState]` is changed/updated?

I searched a lot for the similar problem but I didn't find exactly the same problem.

Comment: You will have to add the deleted table to your query and check that inserted and deleted values are not the same.

Comment: Also I believe SQL Server has a function "IF UPDATE(ColumnName)" that lets you check to see if a certain column was updated.

Comment: @TabAlleman: how is this going to work on a multiple row update, though?

Comment: @TabAlleman one issue with using the UPDATE(ColumnName) is that it returns true if the column is included in the update. It does not account for actual values. In other words it would return true even if the new and old values are the same.

Comment: True, @SeanLange, the IF UPDATE() can be used to spare the processor from performing a query when a column can't possibly have changed, but it does exactly as you say, returns true if the column was included in the update statement, regardless of whether the value changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just needed to add an IF UPDATE check and join deleted table in your trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TransactionDateUpdate]
ON [dbo].[Tasks]
AFTER UPDATE  
AS 
BEGIN
   IF UPDATE(acceptanceState)  --add this line
   UPDATE dbo.Tasks
   SET TransactionDateTime = GETDATE()
   FROM INSERTED i
   JOIN DELETED d on i.TasksID = d.TasksID --add this line
   WHERE i.TasksID = Tasks.TasksID 
END
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! If you could please do me a favor and mark it as accepted answer, that would be wonderful! Thanks!

Comment: I marked it, sorry, I'm new here, I didn't know about this mark before

Comment: No worries! :) I learn something new here everyday! Thanks again!

Comment: only learn about this capability to check which column is updated. new to me !

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to compare the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo table. In an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, the `Deleted` pseudo table contains the old values, while `Inserted` contains the new ones. So if the `Deleted.acceptanceState` is not the same as `Inserted.acceptanceState`, then that column has been updated.

So you need to slightly extend your trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TransactionDateUpdate]
ON [dbo].[Tasks]
AFTER UPDATE  
AS BEGIN
   UPDATE dbo.Tasks
   SET TransactionDateTime = GETDATE()
   FROM Inserted i
   INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.TasksID = d.TasksID
   WHERE i.TasksID = Tasks.TasksID 
     AND i.acceptanceState <> d.acceptanceState
END
```

Comment: Prefer this over the accepted answer. But shouldn't the `WHERE` clause include `null` too? `AND (i.acceptanceState <> d.acceptanceState OR d.acceptanceState IS NULL AND i.acceptanceState IS NOT NULL)`